# SQL Server : SUM() with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I'm using SQL Server and I'm trying to write a query that returns the total distance driven to meetings in 2015, 2016 etc. and then grouping it by year.

What I've got:

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(yyyy, MeetupDate) AS Year, 
    SUM(Distance) AS Distance 
FROM
    Meetups
GROUP BY 
    MeetupDate
```

[Returns this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dX889.png) where `MeetupDate`'s data type is `date` and `Distance` data type is `decimal(5, 2)`

But what I'd like it to do instead is list it as:

```
2015 - NULL
2016 - 97.8 (total)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: use `group by DATEPART(yyyy,MeetupDate)` as you are trying to group by year.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(yyyy, MeetupDate) Year 
    ,SUM(Distance) Distance 
FROM
    Meetups 
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(yyyy, MeetupDate)
```